# authentication using node.js and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication

Guys I am trying to get myself authenticated and for this I am using node.js and mongo DB.But the thing is that after registarion the user is not able to authenticate himself.Here is my snippet

```
app.post('/login',function(req,res){
    ContactProvider.findAll(function(error, posts) {
        var aut = req.body;
        if (aut.user == posts.user && aut.pass == posts.pass) {
            req.session.name = {name:aut.user};
            res.redirect('/home');
        } else {
            res.send('Bad user/pass');
        }
    });
});
```

Below is my snippet for registering the user

```
app.post('/register',function(req, res) {
    var post=req.body;
    if(post.pass!=post.cpass) {
        res.send("Error:Password doesnt match");
    } else {
        ContactProvider.save({
            user: req.param('user'),
            pass: req.param('pass'),
            cpass: req.param('cpass'),
            email: req.param('email')
        }, function(error, docs) {
            res.redirect('/');
        });
    }
});
```

The ContactProvider is the one below where post provider is a different file where all the mongoose things happen

```
var ContactProvider = require('./PostProvider').ContactProvider;
var ContactProvider= new ContactProvider();
```

This is the finone query in the postprovider file

```
ContactProvider.prototype.findone = function(name,pass, callback) {
  Post.findOne({name:name},{pass:pass}, function (err, post) {
                  callback(null, post);

          });
  };
```

Comment: First of all, format your code properly (indents!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something's seriously wrong with your code ( why you use name `posts` for an array of `ContactProvider`? ). You have to search for `ContactProvider` based on username and password. Something like this:

```
app.post('/login',function(req,res){
    var aut = req.body;
    ContactProvider.findOne(
        {
            user: aut.user,
            pass: aut.pass
        },
        function(err, usr) {
            if (error || !usr) {
                res.send('Bad user/pass');
            } else {
                // we have a user, authenticate!
                req.session.name = {name:aut.user};
                res.redirect('/home');
            }
        }
    );
});
```

**SIDE NOTE:** This is a very simple way of authenticating users, but it is not secure at all. You should read more about authentication and security in the internet. Very useful knowledge indeed.

**EDIT:** There's also an issue with your registration. Your data is stored in `post` variable, so use it on `ContactProvider` as well:

```
// some other code
ContactProvider.save({
    user: post.user,
    pass: post.pass,
    cpass: post.cpass, // no need to store the same thing twice
    email: post.email
```

Comment: yeah agreed but the thing is that it always goes to Bad user/pass and trying by your module also produces the same.

Comment: @Nilesh I've updated the answer. It is always a good idea to look directly into the database and see if the correct data goes there.

Comment: yeah but still deres a serious problem in my code.How can i provide you my whole code?

Comment: @Nilesh Are you ready to pay me for these consultations? :) If not, then stick with stackoverflow. You've posted a question, I've answered. IMHO it solves the issue, so you may accept it. If you have other questions, then feel free to post more question on stackoverflow.

Comment: yeah I am sorry but the thing still doesnt work...nyways thanks for your help...!!!

Comment: @Nilesh What do you mean it doesn't work? What exactly is happening? Perhaps the issue is somewhere else?

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not a function...this is the error when i enter the username and password after registration on the login module.!!!

Comment: @Nilesh And you should've started your post with that! What libraries do you use ( related to MongoDB )? What `ContactProvider` is?

Comment: @Nilesh First of all `ContactProvider` should be a **class** not an object. How do you want to query over object? This is all wrong. Remove this line: `var ContactProvider= new ContactProvider();` ( this line essentially closes your access to the class!!! ) or assign different name: `var CurrentContactProvider = new ContactProvider();`. And then use `ContactProvider` with queries. DO NOT ATTACH THINGS TO PROTOTYPE OF `ContactProvider`. That's not a mongoose way to do things. Have you read the documentation??

Comment: nope i am just a starter and followed up these things with the help of examples on github.I am sorry I will follow up with the documentation and then will post here if error persists.

Comment: @Nilesh I know I am a bit harsh on you, but for your own good just remember this simple rule: documentation over everything else. :) If you can't find something in documentation then look elsewhere. Also Mongoose provides a nice tutorial for starters. Good luck! :)

Comment: No sir it was nice talking to you and got some nice lessons to learn from professional like you here.Thanks a lot for your guidance.